Not able to install editable fairseq
File "/tmp/pip-build-env-v52li8xo/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/unixccompiler.py", line 190, in _compile
raise CompileError(msg)
distutils.errors.CompileError: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
/tmp/pip-build-env-v52li8xo/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py:988: _DebuggingTips: Problem in editable installation.
!!
          ********************************************************************************
          An error happened while installing `fairseq` in editable mode.
  
          The following steps are recommended to help debug this problem:
  
          - Try to install the project normally, without using the editable mode.
            Does the error still persist?
            (If it does, try fixing the problem before attempting the editable mode).
          - If you are using binary extensions, make sure you have all OS-level
            dependencies installed (e.g. compilers, toolchains, binary libraries, ...).
          - Try the latest version of setuptools (maybe the error was already fixed).
          - If you (or your project dependencies) are using any setuptools extension
            or customization, make sure they support the editable mode.
  
          After following the steps above, if the problem still persists and
          you think this is related to how setuptools handles editable installations,
          please submit a reproducible example
          (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to:
  
              https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues
  
          See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/development_mode.html for details.
          ********************************************************************************
  
  !!
    cmd_obj.run()
  error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
  [end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building editable for fairseq
Building wheel for antlr4-python3-runtime (setup.py) ... done
Created wheel for antlr4-python3-runtime: filename=antlr4_python3_runtime-4.8-py3-none-any.whl size=141211 sha256=d1bb8adb5bc43cb045c50809c504e51b5005d2e8355265232a22726f42f8b464
Stored in directory: /home/btech/.cache/pip/wheels/42/3c/ae/14db087e6018de74810afe32eb6ac890ef9c68ba19b00db97a
Successfully built antlr4-python3-runtime
Failed to build fairseq
ERROR: Could not build wheels for fairseq, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
I am trying to install fairseq
git clone https://github.com/pytorch/fairseq
cd fairseq
pip install --editable ./
